Play Framework migration: NoSuchMethodError: play.api.ApplicationLoader$.createContext
I am having a problem migrating from Play 2.5 to 2.6. My project builds successfully, but when I try to run it, the following exception message is thrown:
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
play.api.ApplicationLoader$.createContext
(Lplay/api/Environment;Lscala/collection/
immutable/Map;Lscala/Option;Lplay/core/WebCommands;
Lplay/api/inject/DefaultApplicationLifecycle;)
Lplay/api/ApplicationLoader$Context;

If I understand correctly, this class is part of the "play-guice" library. I have checked different versions of this library but could not find anything similar to the "createContext" method.
At thye moment I use "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-guice" % "2.6.0".
Maybe I'm going in the wrong direction. Any help and useful ideas will be greatly appreciated.
error message:
enter image description here
plugins.sbt file content:
enter image description here
java 1.8
sbt.version=0.13.15
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
build.sbt is to long to put as a picture (I can provide additional information if you need it)

Don't post images of text.
